# Formato de fechas

Tags: vba

este es un prototipo simple de la función que necesito porque el problema me surge con el objeto Date que lleva como parámetro el método Weekday, como ven mi función recibe los valores que le ingreso referenciados por celdas y en tipo de dato String. El inconveniente es que si escribo por ej "dd/mm/yyyy" no lo reconoce, debe entrar como "mm/dd/yyyy" pero necesito que en las celdas de mi tabla se vea en el primer formato. Puedo usar de algún modo la cadena "dd/mm/yyyy" y convertirla en "mm/dd/yyyy" con algún método de fechas o algo? O si o si debo recurrir a partición de cadenas y conversion a enteros para crear un objeto date con 3 parámetros numéricos?

Desde ya Gracias

```
Function cantObligaciones(docente As String, fecha As String, art As Integer)
If art = 80 Then
Dim datos As Range
Set datos = Worksheets(2).Range("h5:o10")
col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(fecha, vbMonday)
cantObligaciones = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(docente, datos, col, 1)
End If

End Function
```

GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

Trocea la fecha e intercambia el mes con el día para generar una fecha con el formato que espera la función Weekday:

```
col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Mid(fecha, 4, 2) + "/" + Left(fecha, 2) + "/" + Right(fecha, 4), vbMonday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a convertir la fecha que tienes guardado en texto a un dato tipo fecha antes. PAra ello, usa `Cdate`

> **[Función CDate con VBA](https://www.excel-avanzado.com/2358/funcion-cdate-con-vba.html)**

`col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(CDate(fecha), vbMonday)`